# Convert Linq operation syntax to query syntax

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this method syntax into query syntax:

```
result.Select(c => { c.property1 = 100; return c; }).ToList();
```

Comment: Okay, what have you tried? This query seems relatively simple. What are you stuck on? Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Keeping in mind that StackOverflow is meant to be a repository of searchable questions and answers, please update your question to be more focused on a programming-related problem that may apply to others, and less focused on the exact needs for your very specific situation.

Comment: What is the type of result?

Comment: 1) You can't because LINQ syntax requires an expression (you have a block-bodied lambda) and, 2) Don't mutate within `Select`. Do a `foreach` over `result` (or the result of `ToList`) instead.

Comment: After giving this query a second look, what are you trying to accomplish here? You're using `Select` but you're updating a property on the object within the `Select` statement? This seems like really strange behavior. Is this potentially an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @madreflection, isn't it faster to mutate within Select, which mean I don't have to iterate over the data?

Comment: No, it's no faster that way, you're allocating the same number of enumerators, and it *obscures the side effect*.

Comment: *"I don't have to iterate over the data"* - This makes no sense. The `Select` is iterating over the data in `result`.

Comment: @AtomicallyBeyond Don't worry about what's "faster" because 90% of the time, "faster" doesn't matter because it's not enough faster to make any noticeable difference. First and foremost make your code readable, second make it functional, then if you really want you can worry about speed.

Comment: @Jesse I don't think I'd be quite so cavalier about speed / efficiency, that's how we ended up with 32GB of memory to run a word processor well... but it is important to know when it matters :)

Comment: @NetMage Obviously it does matter to an extent. What I mean is there are very few applications where the performance of a single call makes any noticeable difference. The program as a whole is a completely separate story. If performance becomes a problem, then sure look into it. If not, there's no point in getting caught up in the minute details. Regardless, I still still stand by what I said that the code should be readable first and foremost, functional second, then efficient.

Comment: In general, LINQ is slower than the alternative. If `result` is a `List<>` (C# is a language of types, you should have specified all the types) than the fastest code is a `for` loop indexing the `List<>`, next fastest is a `foreach` and finally LINQ is the slowest. The iteration in your code occurs when the `ToList()` method runs, and it has to chain through the `Select` and call a lambda method on every member of `result`, which isn't needed with a loop.

Comment: Also, what every one else has said about side effects in LINQ. Don't do that unless you really know what you are doing and why. Assuming `result` is a `List<>`, your `ToList()` is just generating a new `List<>` that will be thrown away (waste of time and memory). If not, you should just use `Count()` instead but that is even less clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `record` or `struct` types, you can use the `with` expression to modify an object within a linq expression.

Note that this will make copies of the objects and not modify the original objects. Given the code in your question, the original objects are being modified if they are of reference type.

```
public struct Demo
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

List<Demo> list = new List<Demo>();

var modifiedList = from d in list
                   select d with {Property1 = 100};
```

---

If you want to modify the objects in the list and the objects in the list are of reference type and you are just looking for a concise way of writing the code, use `ForEach` instead of `Select`:

```
public class Demo
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

List<Demo> list = new List<Demo>();

list.ForEach(d => d.Property1 = 100);
```

Note that this will NOT work for value types like `struct` because in that case you would work on copies.

It will also not be a lot more or less efficient than using a traditional `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var d in list) { d.Property1 = 100; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
(from c in result
 select { c.property1 = 100; return c; })
.ToList();
```

Or

```
(from c in result
 select new { c.property1 = 100, c })
.ToList();
```